# Extract unique values from a table in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, unique

I'm working on Google Sheet spreadsheets and I'm looking to get in a column the unique values of the table I show.

Suppose the table has the following values

```
A-B-C
B-C
A-D
```

With the Split function I can separate the values.

```
=SPLIT(B12;"-")

A   B   C
B   C   
A   D
```

I'm stuck on the final point, which is to get the unique values.

```
A 
B 
C 
D
```

Comment: Assuming your data is in columns A:C `=UNIQUE({A1:A3;B1:B3;C1:C3})`. You can also unbind the ranges. `=UNIQUE({A:A;B:B;C:C})`.

Comment: Excelent! that is was I was looking for

Comment: Have added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single formula (sorted, no blanks):

```
=sort(unique(transpose(split(textjoin("-",1,A:A),"-"))))
```

Comment: single formula wins ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in columns `A:C`, `=UNIQUE({A1:A3;B1:B3;C1:C3})`.

You can also unbind the ranges. `=UNIQUE({A:A;B:B;C:C})`.

The curly braces `{}` combine the ranges.

The semi colons `;` tell the curly braces to combine the ranges vertically into a single column for the `UNIQUE` function to parse.